# About Omega prime function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $ω(n)$ be the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.

Is the inequality $ω(n)\leq C\log\log(n)$ true and if so what is the value of the constant $C$ ?

Comment: $\log\log(n)$ is the normal order of $\omega(n)$, see, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order_of_an_arithmetic_function#:~:text=The%20normal%20order%20of%20%CE%A9,log(log(n)).

Comment: @Stopple I want to prove an inequality contains $ω(n)$ like $a^$ω(n)$$$\leq f(n)$ , can I use the above inequality for all values $n$, or it will be changed by changing the value of $n$ ?

Answer (score 10):

On numbers $n$ which are primorials, $$\omega(n)\sim \frac{\log n}{\log \log n},$$
so there is no such general constant. This is because for such $n,$ we have $$n=\prod_{p<x} p = e^{x(1+o(1))}.$$

Answer (score 1):

There is another proof that this equality fails and therefore there is no such value for the constant $C$.

The value of $\omega(2^n-1)$ is at least $d(n)-2$, where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$. This follows from the Bang's theorem as the special case of the Zsigmondy's theorem – see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem.

The inequality

$$d(n)\gt e^{c\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(\ln(n))}}$$

holds for infinitely many $n$ and any constant $c\le\ln(2)$.

This gives

$$n\ge e^{c\frac{\ln(\ln(n))}{\ln(\ln(\ln(n)))}}$$

for any constant $c\le\ln(2)$. This completes the proof.